# Python Selenium - How can I do work this basic code?

Tags: python, selenium

I want to learn to use Selenium but I don't really know what I'm doing wrong. **When I launch my basic script, the Python shell opens and closes immediately without any error message.**

I downloaded Selenium directly from https://pypi.org/project/selenium/, unzipped it and click on setup.py. No error message, just the CMD Windows with "Please press any button".

I downloaded the webdriver for:

1. Chrome - Version 89.
2. Firefox vers 78.6.1esr (64-Bit), just downloaded the last version 0.29.0 - https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases

I put everything in the same order (driver, Selenium, code to execute), see screenshot:
[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Cysz.png)

Here is the code for Firefox:

```
from selenium import webdriver

browser = webdriver.Firefox()
browser.get('https://www.google.com')
```

I also tried by giving directly the path of the Driver **without success** :

```
from selenium import webdriver

browser = webdriver.Firefox('C:\Users\Bast01\Desktop\Python\Selenium Test\geckodriver.exe')
browser.get('https://www.google.com')
```

I even don't know if Selenium is corretly installed, for example:

```
Python 3.9.1 (tags/v3.9.1:1e5d33e, Dec  7 2020, 17:08:21) [MSC v.1927 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> help("selenium")
No Python documentation found for 'selenium'.
Use help() to get the interactive help utility.
Use help(str) for help on the str class.

>>> help("Selenium")
No Python documentation found for 'Selenium'.
Use help() to get the interactive help utility.
Use help(str) for help on the str class.
```

Thank you for your help !

Comment: There seems to be a lot of different questions lumped together here. Is your first trouble-shooting question actually something like “How do I check if Selenium is correctly installed?”

Comment: My question would be: according to these informations, can anyone tell why it's not working ? Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

just install selenium from the pip repository directly than trying to build it from source.

use

```
 pip install selenium
```

now if you do help("selenium")

you gets:

[image]

## if you still want to install using setup.py then use below method:

open selenium-3.141.0\selenium-3.141.0 ( the extracted ) folder where setup.py was the current directory in cmd/terminal and then run

```
 pip install .
```

or

```
 python setup.py install
```